# checkValidity() not showing any html5 error notifications when fields are empty and posting with Ajax

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, forms

I have a form that posts using Ajax, I also want to set an HTML5 `required` attribute on some input fields, but this stops working as expected with Ajax.

So I did the following:

```
$("body").on("click",".register-button",function(e){
    e.preventDefault();

    if($('#registerform')[0].checkValidity()){
        registerform = $(".register-form").serialize();

        $.ajax({
         type:'post',
         url:"includes/registreren.php",
         data:({registerform: registerform}),
         success:function(data){
             var content = $( $.parseHTML(data) );
             $( "#registerresult" ).empty().append( content );
         }
     });
 }else{

 }
});
```

This way the form is not posted when empty, but I also don't get any notifications that fields are empty like I would get when only using HTML to post.

I also tried logging the validity like so:

```
$("body").on("click",".register-button",function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
        $check = $('#registerform')[0].checkValidity();

        console.log($check);

        registerform = $(".register-form").serialize();

        $.ajax({
         type:'post',
         url:"includes/registreren.php",
         data:({registerform: registerform}),
         success:function(data){
             var content = $( $.parseHTML(data) );
             $( "#registerresult" ).empty().append( content );
         }
     });
});
```

Which shows `false` in my console when empty. So the code works, why are the HTML5 notifications not shown? I remember doing something similar in the past and I didn't have to add any custom error messages then, it just worked.

This is my HTML markup:

```
<form id="registerform" class="register-form" method="post">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <input type="text" name="voornaam" placeholder="Voornaam" required>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <input type="text" name="achternaam" placeholder="Achternaam" required>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <input type="text" name="bedrijf"  placeholder="Bedrijfsnaam (optioneel)">
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <input type="text" name="telefoon" placeholder="Telefoonnummer" required>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <input type="text" name="email" placeholder="E-mail" required>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-3">
            <input type="text" name="huisnummer" id="billing_streetnumber" placeholder="Huisnummer" required>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-3">
            <input type="text" name="tussenvoegsel" placeholder="Tussenvoegsel" required>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <input type="text" name="postcode" id="billing_postcode" placeholder="Postcode" required>
        </div>
        <div id="postcoderesult" class="col-lg-12">
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-6">
                <input type="text" name="straat" placeholder="Straatnaam" readonly required>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-6">
                <input type="text" name="woonplaats" placeholder="Woonplaats" readonly required>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <input type="password" name="password" placeholder="Wachtwoord (minimaal 6 tekens)" required>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <input type="password" name="confirmpassword"placeholder="Herhaal wachtwoord" required>
        </div>
        <div id="registerresult">

        </div>
    </div>
    <button type="button" name="submit" class="register-button">Account aanmaken</button>
</form>
```

What am I missing?

Comment: One way would be to use `reportValidity()`. It triggers the native html5 form validation UI. Just attach it to the form element and trigger it

Comment: Thank you, that is what I was looking for! @akshithDayanand